# Code under if-statement performing under false conditions in python

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I want the block of code under the if-statement to only run if the word "trip" is found in that particular line. However, my print output indicates that even the lines without the word "trip" are in the result. This is the code:

```
for line in file:
    #match = re.search(r'\rTrip', line)
    #if match:
    if line.find('\rTrip') != -1:
        someArray = []
        times = re.compile(r'\d+:\d+')
        miles = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+')
        names = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]{2,25}||\s[A-Za-z]{2,25}')

        nam = line.split('\rTrip')

        num = line.split()

        drivenTimes = times.findall(str(num))
        drivenMiles = miles.findall(str(num))

        driverNames = names.findall(str(nam))
        someArray.append(line)
        print(line)
```

Comment: `line.find('\rTrip') != -1` should use `==`, but i don't think it should ever be -1

Comment: What's up with the `\r`?

Comment: When using `for line in file`, the lines won't begin with `\r`, so your condition is never true.  Why are you searching for `\rTrip` instead of just `Trip`?

Comment: None of them them work, \rTrip and Trip both doesn't work.The \r in \rTrip I'm guessing is for reading new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substring matching in python can be accomplished using the `in` operator.  IE:

```
if 'trip' in line:
  # Code here for the presence of "trip"
```

Comment: Hi g.d.d.c      I have just tried this to the same end. It doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @SylvesterAmponsah - then you're not dealing with what you think you are.  `for line in file` will take an open file and return individual lines from it.  That `if` statement will _absolutely only_ be true if `"trip"`, all in lower case, appears in the line in question.  Period.  Full stop.  If you're not seeing that behavior, then you're not iterating a file.  Try placing a call to `print(line)` as the very first line in your `for` loop.  See what that spits out.

Comment: the output from placing a call to the first line in the for loop is the same as the output from the code above.

Comment: I printed the file in atom and all the text was in one line that's why the code didn't work but your suggestion definitely works after the change. thank you

Answer (score 0):

See correct code here !!!

```
import re

with open('C:\\Users\\Grace\\Documents\\test.txt', 'r') as lines:
       line2=lines.read().split('\n')    
       for line in line2:
               if line.find('Trip') == -1:

                  someArray = []

                 times = re.compile(r'\d+:\d+')
                 miles = re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+')
                 names = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]{2,25}||\s[A-Za-z]{2,25}')

                 nam = line.split('\rTrip')


                 num = line.split()

                 drivenTimes = times.findall(str(num))
                 drivenMiles = miles.findall(str(num))



                driverNames = names.findall(str(nam))
                someArray.append(line)
                print(line)
```

Comment: Grace, this approach doesn't work either. All the line are printed in the output.

Comment: it worked correctly for me, maybe i need to see sample of your input file

Comment: Hi Grace, thanks for your help. It turns out all the text was in a single line. I printed the text out in atom and it was all in a single line. That explains why the code didn't work. thanks a bunch